# How to make smooth frame animation in android?

Tags: android, animation, imageview, frame, transition

I made a frame animation. But the transitition between images is bad looking. How can I apply a crossfade effect to it ?

When using `TransitionDrawable` i get the proper result but it stops after one execution.

Any one has an idea how to resolve it?

```
public void startAnimation() {
    if (logoAnimation != null) {
        if (logoAnimation.isRunning()) {
            logoAnimation.stop();
        }
        logoAnimation.start();
    }
}

private int setLogoAnimation(int animationID, int targetID) {
    imageView = (ImageView) window.findViewById(targetID);
    imageView.setImageResource(animationID);
    logoAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();

    if (imageView != null && logoAnimation != null) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Than I simply run it by object.startAnimation(); I works, but the animation is ugly and I need it to be smooth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to crossfade between two pictures, why not use an AlphaAnimation which will alter the transparency of two views and will create the effect that you require.

Create two animations:

res/anim/fadeout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
```

res/anim/fadein.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
```

and then override the default transition between activities:

```
startActivity( new Intent( this, SecondActivity.class ) );
overridePendingTransition( R.anim.fadeout, R.anim.fadein );
```

or you can apply animations to specific widgets:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( this, R.anim.fadeout );
image1.startAnimation( animation );
```

I am currently in the middle of a series on animation on my [blog](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/129) which may give you some further information.

Comment: Thats not it. I have a main activity with some buttons. I made a custom titlebar, where the animation should work. Theres an ImageView in this titlebar which should animate throughout the whole process. I managed to animate it using frame animation. Now i want to add the crossfade effect. How do i acheieve it ?

Comment: Look at my answer again, I explain how to apply animations to specific widgets as well as to transitions between activities.

Comment: I'm not sure if I know what do you mean exactly. I dont want to change transition between activites, because they're fine. I want to change the transition effect in the ImageView animation. Having 'imageView.startAnimation(alphaAnimation)' doesn't work when frame animation is set.

Comment: As I have now said three times: you can apply animations to specific widgets (i.e. two ImageView instances) by calling startAnimation on those widgets.

Comment: Ok Thanks I get it all now. I came across other issue, I'm writing the App for android 1.6 and it doesnt supper overridePendindTransition. Any idea how to resolve it ?

Comment: I'm still in dead point. The animation doesnt work as it should. Anyone could help ?

Answer (score 0):

By using frame animation increasing frame number can help you to get a good result. In my case the result was satisfactory on my HTC Evo.

While using tween animation you can use linear interpolator. For rotation for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<rotate  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:fromDegrees="0"  
    android:toDegrees="359"  
    android:pivotX="50%"  
    android:pivotY="50%"  
    android:repeatCount="infinite"  
    android:duration="1000"  
    android:interpolator="@anim/linear_interpolator" />
```

And you interpolator file content here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<linearInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

This is for rotation, you can see full list here.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

or you can read a blog post that I write how to make a loading animation.

http://yekmer.posterous.com/how-to-make-a-loading-animator-in-android

Comment: the thing is that I have only two pictures and i want and effect like in TranistionDrawable. So the elements crossfade each other.

Comment: You can use AnimationDrawable class setOneShot(boolean oneShot) method to get a non-stop animation

Comment: thanks but that is not an issue. I have an ImageView, where I want to animate 2 pictures. Those two pictures should crossfade each other.