# How to resize drawable items(images) in progress bar when doing custom animation?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview, android-animation, android-progressbar

I have a list view, which contains an icon, a title and a subtitle.

My boss asks me that he wants to change that icon into something animation. When he mean animation, it is just display three images continues, makes it look like animation.

I already make the animation work, by writing a xml in res/anim folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<animation-list android:oneshot="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:duration="150" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_anmi_1"/>
    <item android:duration="150" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_anmi_2" />
    <item android:duration="150" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_anmi_3" />
</animation-list>
```

And by writing another progress bar style in value folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="animStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small">
        <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@anim/icon_anim</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I using progress bar since the icon should start animation automatic. Which it does. Also, in my list adapter's xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="60dip"
 android:padding="10dip"
 >

<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/itemIcon" style="@style/animStyle"
        android:layout_width="60px" 
        android:layout_height="60px"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/itemInfo"
 android:layout_width="240dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemIcon"
 android:gravity="center_vertical"
 android:textSize="18sp"
 android:textStyle="bold"
 android:ellipsize="marquee" android:singleLine="true"/>
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/subtitle"
 android:layout_width="240dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemIcon"
 android:gravity="center_vertical"
 android:textSize="10sp"
 android:ellipsize="marquee" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_below="@+id/itemInfo"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I also make changes in my code when binding adapter to list item:

```
adapterForList= new SimpleAdapter(this, hashMapListForListView, R.layout.s_item, new String[]{"imageUri","title","subtitle"},new int[]{R.id.itemIcon,R.id.itemInfo,R.id.subtitle});
        adapterForList.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                    String textRepresentation) {
                if (view.getId() == R.id.itemIcon) {
                    //Not need progress
                    //int value = Integer.parseInt(data.toString());
                    //((ProgressBar) view).setProgress(value);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        lv.setAdapter(adapterForList);
```

The animation works fine. The only problem I face now is that the image I put for animation can't be resized to the correct size. It can only display part of it. I wonder if there is a way to let me define the size of the image to display so it could be work as fine as a image view.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved through various techniques, depending on the target platform. If you're targetting API 11 or higher, a ViewFlipper can perform the animation instead.

However as you're attempting the ProgressBar solution to an animation I suppose you're targetting older versions of Android as well. The problem can be solved in these cases by reverting back to an ImageView and setting the drawable of the image from a timer.

The technique is described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14991972/1950496 and can be modified to fit the RemoteViews issue.